# Possible price combinations

Tags: combinations

A, B and C are prices of a good at $3$ points in time respectively. How many price combinations are possible. Please provide me a formula as well.

Example,

1. $A=B=C$
2. $A>B>C$
3. $A>B$ and $C>A$
4. $A>B$ and $C<A$
5. $A>B$ and $A>C$ and $B>C$
6. $A>B$ and $A<C$ and $B>C$
7. $A>B$ and $A=C$ and $B>C$

so the possible combinations should consider "$>$" ,"$<$" "$ \lor $",  " $=$ " in every possible way

Comment: How is 7) possible?

Comment: Yes "7" is not possible, I just wrote on a paper by a standard order and it all messed up....thats why I need a precise formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called "Fubini numbers" or the number of "preferential arrangements":
http://oeis.org/A000670

Answer (score 1):

With $2$ "$=$", there is $1$ chance. 
$\\$

With $1$ "$=$", there is $3+3$ chances. ($3!/2$ different ordering for first $>$ then $=$ (Ex: $a>b=c$ (note that $a>b=c$ and $a>c=b$ is same)) and $3!/2$ different ordering for first $=$ then $>$ (Ex: $a=b>c$ (note that $a=b>c$ and $b=a>c$ is same)) )
$\\$

With $0$ "$=$", there is $6$ chances. ($3!$ different ordering (Ex: $a>b>c$))
$\\$

Total $=13$ chances.

Answer (score 1):

You have

or $$number <number < number$$

or  $$number = number < number$$

or $$number < number = number$$

So for each string you have 6 posibilities in 1. case and 3 posibilities in case 2. and 3. that is 12 posibilities. You have also posibilite that all are equal so you have 13 posibilites in total.

What about $$number >number > number\;\;\;?$$
Well, all those are already counted in $number <number < number$. Say $a>b>c$ is the same as $c<b<a$.

Comment: What about $a=b<c$ and $b=a<c$?  You have counted those as two arrangements, but aren't they the same?  (I suppose you could argue  they are distinct, but then to be consistent you would have to count $a=b=c$ and $b=a=c$ as distinct also.)

Comment: Yes, you are right! @awkward Thanks for pointing that out